# $f = \partial (\sum_i n_i \sigma_i)$ with each $n_i=\pm 1$ implies $K$ is an orientable surface

Tags: algebraic-topology

Hatcher gives this statement as an exercise in the paragraph at the end of the proof of Thm 2A.1 in his algebraic topology book. The $\sigma_i$'s are singular $2$-chains, and here $K$ is a $\Delta$ complex associated to the sum $\sum_i n_i \sigma_i$ obtained by identifying certain pairs of edges of a disjoint union of $\Delta$ simplices corresponding one to one to the $\sigma_i$'s in the sum. It's also worth mentioning that $f$ is a loop such that it is the boundary of some $n$-chain given as the sum.

Can someone help me understand why this statement is true?

Comment: And what is $f$?

Comment: $f$ in this case is the boundary of the $n$ chain expressed as a sum, but moreover, the 1-simplex $f$ is also a loop. I've edited the post.